# pedulilindungi app "identity photo can't be empty" error

Tags: covid-19, indonesia, vaccinations

We are going to Indonesia and apparently you need to download pedulilindungi app and add you vaccine info. I did fill out everything as required including an upload of my passport but when I hit sumbit I get an "identity photo can't be empty" error. I have no idea how to proceed.

1. Has anyone done this recently and has an idea what I'm doing wrong?
2. Do I actually need to upload anything if we stay for less than 30 days ?

I read something that you get automatic green status for 30 days on arrival and you only need proof of vaccination if you want to stay more than 30 days, but all of this seems to be quite  poorly documented.

Comment: IATA claims that pedulilindungi is unfortunately still mandatory.

Comment: As far as I can tell IATA just claims that you need to download the app, but but what you actually need to do with it and what information is required for entry.

Comment: I was in Indonesia (Bintan) last year and PeduliLindungi was never checked anywhere (airline, health check, immigration). YMMV.

Comment: I was in Indonesia two weeks ago, PeduliLindungi was never checked anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the real-life feedback. That's very helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I entered Indonesia in November by ferry (Batam from Singapore), they accepted the printouts of my EU-vaccination status with the QR-code on it. I had Pedulilindungi installed, but I did not show that one when entering.

I entered Indonesia again in December by plane (Kualanamu from Kuala Lumpur), and that time had showed Pedulilindungi vaccination status. I don't know if they would also have accepted the EU-vaccination certificate with the QR code.

Within 10 weeks, I used Pedulilindungi three times: once while entering Indonesia in Medan, see above; once showed it to enter the airport when taking a domestic flight (forgot which one, probably YIA); once to check in while visiting a mall.

So, if you have Pedulilindungi, there should be no problem. If you can't register all documents within the app as required, make sure to install the app and set up everything you can. Bring the original documents with you, including printouts of the EU vaccination status with QR code (or equivalent if you are not from the EU). If asked for your vaccination status, show the original documents.

In Indonesia, as long as you are friendly and ask for help and are not being rude to personnel, everyone will try their best to help you and I cannot imagine you not being allowed from entering the country as long as you are carrying the original documents.

Comment: I'd also note that the pandemic is defacto over and it's increasingly unlikely anyone will be making a serious effort to enforce the rules at this point. So OP should be good to go :-)